# Second yAxis does not scale according to series in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have created a Highchart in which there are two y-axes. My problem is the second yAxis (on the opposite side) does not scale according to the series which I have specifically attach to it in the options (`yAxis: 1`).

http://jsfiddle.net/sushengloong/MMwSv/

In the jsfiddle above, it's obvious that the Price axis has much bigger extreme as compared to the two line series. This makes the two line series look much flatter.

When I take away Price 1 series by clicking on the legend, yAxis can then scale correctly based on Price 2 series but not the other way round. This is really strange and I am not sure if I have missed out anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set [`alignTicks: false`](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.alignTicks),  see: http://jsfiddle.net/MMwSv/2/

From docs:

> **alignTicks: Boolean**
>
> When using multiple axis, the ticks of two or more opposite axes will automatically be aligned by adding ticks to the axis or axes with the least ticks, as if `tickAmount` were specified.
>
> This can be prevented by setting `alignTicks` to false. If the grid lines look messy, it's a good idea to hide them for the secondary axis by setting `gridLineWidth` to 0.
>
> If `startOnTick` or `endOnTick` in an Axis options are set to false, then the `alignTicks` will be disabled for the Axis.
>
> Disabled for logarithmic axes.
>
> Defaults to `true`.

Comment: for anyone else who may need it too, please notice the comment at to API docs [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.alignTicks): 
**If the grid lines look messy, it's a good idea to hide them for the secondary axis by setting gridLineWidth to 0**

Comment: great solution - but what I don't understand is why this option makes any difference for only **one** opposite axis (which I believe is the most use case anyway) as the API seems to say it's to align ticks for **two or more opposite axes**. I guess I don't even understand why aligning ticks should be affecting auto-scaling at all regardless. This smells like a bug or hacky implementation to me.

Comment: Oh, it's a mistake in the docs. `opposite` option does not change anything. What does matter: width, height and top/left options for an axis (so axes "match" each other).